# Launch Template reference latest AMI built by codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, amazon-ami, aws-auto-scaling, launch-template

I have codepipeline that creates an AMI and I have created separate Cloudformation stack to create Launch template that uses the AMI. Currently the Launch Template Cloudformation has the AMI imageID hard-coded like this

```
LaunchTemplate:
    Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
    Properties:
      LaunchTemplateData:
        ImageId: ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

What's the best way to update LaunchTemplate to always use the latest imageId built by codepipe line?

Comment: Is your question answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661858/aws-how-to-make-asg-always-use-the-latest-ami?

Comment: @LRutten Not really. Now I know Launch Templates are immutable so sounds like I need to create a new Launch Template version for every AMI build, and the make the ASG to use that latest version. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It's quite a tricky thing to do this with cloudformation, since CFN only updates infra when you run an `update-stack`.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Parameters:
  Amiid:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /aws/...<ssm parameter name for your AMI family>
```

This way CFN will fetch the latest AMI ID from SSM

Then use this parameter in

```
ImageId: !Ref Amiid
```